# How to set button image to nil in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

In a reset button where I want to reset my game when I try to set my image to nil Xcode displays this error:

> Could not cast value of type 'UIView' (0x106c26e88) to 'UIButton'
>   (0x106c2cf68).

**This is my code:**

```
    var button : UIButton
    for var  i = 0; i < 9; i++ {

        button = self.view.viewWithTag(i) as! UIButton

        button.setImage(nil, forState: .Normal)
    }
```

Comment: The view you are trying to cast isn't a button..

Comment: it look like the problem is in the tag when i set i = 1 the code work fine... i change all my label to a different tag rather than 0 and am trying to find what's the problem with 0.

Comment: I think more code will be needed, it seems like a logical error

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who finds this issue and is trying to solve the problem from the title,

```
button.setImage(nil, for: .normal)
```

should produce the desired result.

(Added my answer to this post as it was the first result in Google.)

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is set the contents to the path of the file as empty or invalid

`let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: "")`

Answer (score 1):

You can insert nil image to your button as

```
  let btnCheckMarkImage = UIImage(CGImage: nil)
  checkBoxbtn.setImage(btnCheckMarkImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Comment: Got this error: 'nil' is not compatible with expected argument type 'CGImage'

Answer (score 0):

By the error, the problem seems to be that one of the tagged views you are trying to cast as UIButton isn't really an UIButton class object

Answer (score 0):

I found my view tag = 0 and this is what make the app crash

[image]